# using malloc to allocate pointers

Tags: malloc

If you want to allocate a integer my understanding is that you do this:

```
int* x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

If I understand correctly malloc will allocate an integer on the heap and return a pointer to it which will then be stored in x. If I wanted to allocated an int* instead would I do this?

```
int** x = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

In general, does malloc return a point to the type that it just created? When you do this it looks like you are casting the pointer that malloc returns but not casting the actual memory that malloc allocated. Why is that?

Comment: You are casting the void pointer returned from malloc.  In C, you don't even need to cast.  It is done implicitly on assignment.

Comment: so the casting i'm doing is not nessisary?

Comment: in C it is not necessary to cast.  In C++, it will fail to compile without the cast.

Comment: why don't i need to cast the memory allocated by malloc?

Comment: The second statement will allocate a pointer to an int, but will not allocate the int itself (I'm guessing this is the cause of the confusion...)

Comment: thats what i was trying to do with the second statment

Comment: what i'm confused about is how the memory the is allocated is being cast

Comment: @fred You're not doing anything with the memory by casting.  It has to do with the type system of the two languages.  C allows implicit casting from void* to T.  C++ wants the programmer to explicitly cast.

Comment: ok thanks, i think i get it now

Comment: @fred malloc will always return a void*.  No matter what you allocate with, you will get back a void*.